# Commerce (and Commerce Kickstart) rendering add-to-cart buttons on any page?

Tags: commerce

Can someone school me or point me to a resource where I can learn how to render the add-to-cart buttons for specific products on any page? I know how to get them in a view and I'm using Commerce Kickstart.

The goal is simple, for the slider, I'd like to include an add-to-cart button for the slideshow product in the slide itself. The slides are content but they're not controlled by a view as Commerce Kickstart has it's own module for the slideshow. Even if it were a view, I don't think it would help.

So is there a way to print out an add-to-cart (even in PHP) like finding the add-to-cart variable for a product by id or something and just rendering it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: Experimenting I added a product variation field to the Slideshow content type. This essentially creates a new line item type but that's okay. I can now render the field in the view and it adds to the cart like it's supposed to. Just some CSS now and it will be just fine.

Comment: So one problem I found is that the Slideshow now becomes a product display so the content view will no longer display it when you go to admin/content and you cannot create a new slideshow unless you go to add products instead of add content. So you have to remove the filter "is a product display" from the content view or else you will never see the slideshow items.